# Rollup/Vite: Add additional file to the compilation from plugin so that other plugins can run against it

Tags: vite, rollupjs

I'm trying to develop a Rollup/Vite plugin that can add additional CSS assets to the compilation. These are files that are otherwise unreferenced, and therefore not part of the compilation.

The issue that I'm running into, and it's likely that I'm misusing/misunderstanding something, is that while I can use `this.emitFile()` and get the desired file output, it is seemingly separate to the compilation as a whole; it will not be passed to other plugins. In this case, I'd like these CSS assets to be passed to Vite's CSS plugin, which comes later in the pipeline, but it never sees these assets in [its `transform()` hook](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/blob/45c6f3b7601afcb8fccf25864703ee6b50a10da8/packages/vite/src/node/plugins/css.ts#L254).

This is a simplified view of what I'm using:

```js
export function myPlugin() {
  async function handleContent(id) {
    ...
    const r = this.emitFile({
      type: 'asset',
      name: ...
    });

    fs.readFile(...).then(s => this.setAssetSource(r, s));
  }

  return {
    name: 'my-plugin',
    enforce: 'pre',
    async buildStart(opts) {
      const entries = Object.values(opts.input);
      await Promise.all(entries.map(handleContent.bind(this)));  
      ...
    }
  } 
}
```

Is `this.emitFile()` wrong? Is there some other way I should be adding new files?